# Do sum for multiple values of same date in foreach loop for attendance sheet

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am making attendance sheet date wise. There are multiple values in one filed for attendance status like 1 for present 0 for absent and 3 for not responded.

For example:

```
Site    Date    Present Absent  Not Responded
BAY 2015-08-02  1          0     0  
BAY 2015-08-02  1          1     0  
BAY 2015-08-03  1          1     0    
BIS 2015-08-03  1          0     0
```

For BAY this date 2015-08-02 should display one row and present value should 2, but I am getting two rows.

This is my code:

```
public function attendanc_disc($site_id)
{
    $y=date('Y-m');
    $sql = "SELECT sch.*"
            ." FROM #__schedule AS sch"
            ." WHERE sch.start_date like '%".$y."%' and sch.site_id='".$site_id."' order by sch.start_date ASC"
            ;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

I am displaying this loop to call function like this:

```
foreach ($sch_rows as $sch) {



                if ($sch->reply_status_id == 1) {
                    $presentcnt +=1;
                    $class = 'success';
                } else if ($sch->reply_status_id == 0) {
                    $not_res +=1;
                    $class = 'warning';
                } else if ($sch->reply_status_id == 6) {
                    $CB_res +=1;
                    $class = 'alert-info';
                } else {
                    $absent +=1;
                    $class = 'alert-danger';
                }


                $html .='<tr ><td class="' . $class . '"><a href="admin/schedule/assignment/true/' . $site->id . '" >' . $site->code . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/1/' . $site->id . '">' . $sch->start_date . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/1/' . $site->id . '">' . $presentcnt . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/1/' . $site->id . '">' . $absent . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/2/' . $site->id . '">' . $CB_res . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/3/' . $site->id . '">' . $not_res . '</a></td><td><a href="index.php/admin/home/att_report/4/' . $site->id . '">' . $CB_res . '</a></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use case in your sql

```
CASE
    WHEN Responded== 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
end
```

Or the other way you have to use if else in your sql and use count keyword to get total presents

```
$sql = "SELECT sch.start_date,COUNT(IF(reply_status_id = '1', 1,0)) AS `presentcnt`,COUNT(IF(reply_status_id = '0', 1,0)) AS `not_res  FROM #__schedule AS sch WHERE sch.start_date like '%".$y."%' and sch.site_id='".$site_id."' order by sch.start_date ASC";
```